# Saveall issue with multiple associated model in cakephp 1.3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

```
$data['Order']['amount'] = 10;
$data['Orderdetail'] = array( 
     0 => array( 'unitprice' => 1, 'amount' => 2, 'discount' => 1, 'skunit_id' => 1,                    
        'batch_id' => 0, 'vat' => 0, 'schemediscount' => 0, 'quantity' => 1, 'amount' => 10 ), 
   1=> array( 'unitprice' => 1, 'amount' => 2, 'discount' => 1, 'skunit_id' => 1,   
       'batch_id' => 0, 'vat' => 0, 'schemediscount' => 0, 'quantity' => 1, 'amount' => 10 ));

$b = $this->Order->saveAll( $data )
```

I am using this code. I have also defined association in model like

```
var $hasMany = array(
    'Orderdetail' => array(
        'className' => 'Orderdetail',
        'foreignKey' => 'order_id',
        'dependent' => false,
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'exclusive' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
        'counterQuery' => ''
    ));
```

but both data is not getting saved..is it cakephp 1.3 issue or I am doing some mistake..any kind of help will be appreciated. 
Still not solved...any body have tried??

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need load a model that you are using, so:

```
$this->loadModel('Order');
$b = $this->Order->saveAll( $data )
```